# Extracting a column from a specific multi-dimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble while attempting to extract a row from my array. This is my code :

```
using System;

namespace C_sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!. This is the one !");

            dynamic[] res = new Object[3];

            res[0] = new int[2,2]{{3,2},{16,9}};
            res[1] = new int[2,2]{{4,7},{6,29}};
            res[2] = new int[2,2]{{30,29},{5,49}};

            //dynamic resultat = res[0][0];

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, at the end of my program, the contents of my local variable `res` looks like this :

```
[0] [dynamic]:{int[2, 2]}
[0, 0] [int]:3
[0, 1] [int]:2
[1, 0] [int]:16
[1, 1] [int]:9
[1] [dynamic]:{int[2, 2]}
[0, 0] [int]:4
[0, 1] [int]:7
[1, 0] [int]:6
[1, 1] [int]:29
[2] [dynamic]:{int[2, 2]}
[0, 0] [int]:30
[0, 1] [int]:29
[1, 0] [int]:5
[1, 1] [int]:49
```

Now, I want to put only the first row of `res[0]` in my variable `resultat` in order to get a 1D array. So, at the end of the process, `resultat` should be equal to :

```
[0] [int]:3
[1] [int]:2
```

I've already tried `res[0][0,]` and `res[0][0:]`. None of them worked. Any help ?

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic[]` instead of `int[][,]`?

Comment: with `dynamic[]`, I can access to any value of my matrix by doing for example`res[0][i,j]`. It's impossible with types `Object` (and `int` is also an `Object`)

Comment: have you tried `selectMany(predicate())` ?

Comment: So...? You can do that with `int[][,]` if you do it properly: `int[][,] res = new int[3][,];`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, you're right. But in my project, I'm using other kind of types structures, I've just pasted the above snippet to give an example.
Now, I'm dealing with large amount of data and I want colunm by colunm. Any idea ?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten 2d array using `.Cast<int>()` and then take first row using `.Take(2)`:

```
const int arraySize = 2;
var resultat = (res[0] as int[,]).Cast<int>().Take(arraySize).ToArray();
```

In general case for an arbitrary row index you can use `.Skip(arraySize * rowIndex)`

If it is too slow for you, you may try `Buffer.BlockCopy`:

```
const int rowSize = 2;
const int intSize = 4;

int[] resultat = new int[rowSize];
Buffer.BlockCopy(res[0], 0, resultat, 0, intSize * rowSize);
```

In general case it would be

```
const int intSize = 4; // Size of integer type in bytes

int[,] matrix = res[0];

int rowSize = matrix.GetLength(1); // Get size of second 2d-array dimension

int rowIndex = 0; // Index of a row you want to extract

int[] resultat = new int[rowSize];
Buffer.BlockCopy(res[0], // Copy source
            rowSize * intSize * rowIndex, // Source offset in bytes
            resultat, // Copy destination
            0,  // Destination offset
            intSize * rowSize); // The number of bytes to copy
```

[Buffer.BlockCopy documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer !! :D
I'm using your last code : `Buffer.BlockCopy`. The problem is that I'm testing with different values of listed parameter (`arraySize`, `intSize` and `rowIndex`) and I'm having `OutOfBound Exception`. So, I'm not sure to know exactly what these parameters really mean.

Comment: And to add more details, in my example `res[0]` returns only 2 elements to `resultat` but in my project I don't heve a prior knowledge of how many elements should be returned to my variable `resultat`.

Comment: @BoubacarTraoré intSize means size of an integer - 4 bytes, it should be properly changed if you use another type.

Comment: @BoubacarTraoré use .GetLength(1) to get it. I have edited the answer, hope now it's more clear.

Comment: You're a genius @Bagdan Gilevich, it definitively solved my problem !!
Thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: It seems like c# is really difficult than python when dealing with data. It would be great to have a pandas like in C#.